# How to get a related model through a pivot table in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, relationship, laravel-query-builder

i have a bit of a problem in my Laravel 5.4 application, in my database i have several entities that are related through a central model called **Content** like such.

```
Actor     -> actors_contents     -> Content
Category  -> categories_contents -> Content
```

---

And then i have three other entities that are "contents" like Video, Photo etc...

```
Video (content_id)  -> Content
Photo (content_id)  -> Content
Stream (content_id) -> Content
```

What i want is to be able to, for instance access all of the Videos for a particular Actor from the Actor model, while also being able to directly get the Actors inside of the Video Model.

So essentially, get the content_id for the current Actor from a pivot table and then find the Videos that match it.

I was trying to use **hasManyThrough** but after reading for a while i found that it doesn't work with Many-to-many relationships, so my question is how can i make this work otherwise?
I don't want to have to define my own Relationships or anything like that, i could i guess create a method on the Model that simply does some joins to get the values i want, but does that have implications behind the scenes when compared to Laravel's Relationships?

For one

```
 ->with(['relation'])
```

Would no longer work with this relationship and as such i wouldn't be able to eager load it and that might be a bit of a problem, so how would you guys solve this problem? 
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

> What I want is to be able to, for instance, access all of the Videos for a particular Actor

One way to do that is to use `whereHas()`:

```
$actorName = 'John Travolta';
Video::whereHas('content', function ($q) use ($actorName) {
        $q->whereHas('actors', function ($q) use ($actorName) {
            $q->where('name', $actorName);
        });
    })->get();
```

Comment: That works, but that means i cannot eager load the relationship and would have to create an additional wrapper class or repository for that custom query if there's no other option then i'll have to do it that way but it's unfortunate

Comment: @JonnySerra you can eager load data. Just add `with()` to the query.